# Mocking hibernate using mockmvc and mockito

Tags: hibernate, junit, mockito

I am using hibernate in my project and below is my java code.

```
 public class TestInstancesDaoImpl implements TestInstancesDao {
  private final static String sqlQueryForTestInstances = 
  "SELECT tc.testCycleId,tc.testId,tc.status,
   tc.executionDate,tc.executionTime,tc.testInstanceNumber,
   tc.testerName,tc.testId,t.testName,t.testType,
   tc.analysis from TestInstance tc, Test t where tc.cycleId = :cycleId"
   "AND tc.testId = t.testId ORDER BY tc.executionDate desc,tc.executionTime desc";

 public List<TestInstance> getAllTestInstances(String domainName,
             String projectName, Long testSetId,String server) throws CustomException {
       String dbName = almDatabaseDao.getDBName(domainName, projectName, server);
       List<TestInstance> testInstanceList = new ArrayList<TestInstance>();
       List<?> list = null;
       Transaction tx = null;
   try {
      tx = session.beginTransaction();
      Query q = session.createQuery(sqlQueryForTestInstances);
      q.setParameter("cycleId", testSetId);
      list = q.list();
      StringBuilder testCycleIds = new StringBuilder();
      ListIterator<?> it = list.listIterator();
      while (it.hasNext()) {
      Object[] testInstanceObject = (Object[]) it.next();
      if (testInstanceObject[0] != null) {
        int testCycleId =Integer.parseInt(testInstanceObject[0].toString());
        testInstance.setTestCycleId(testCycleId);
        testInstanceList.add(testInstance);
       }
      }
   } catch (Exception e) {
      if (tx != null) {
      tx.rollback();
    }
  } finally {
    session.close();
}
return testInstanceList;
}
```

Below is my unit test code.
Error thrown - 
*java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;* while iterating through list
**Object[] testInstanceObject = (Object[]) it.next();**

List returned from hibernate will be in the form of below structure -
**[[Ljava.lang.Object;@79e2764b, [Ljava.lang.Object;@2c47471]]**

How to construct the above list for mocking similar to that of list returned from hibernate?Cananyone help me on how to achieve the issue?

```
 @Test
 public void testGetAllTestInstancesImpl(){
  String domain = "XXX";
  String server = "XXX";
  String projectName = "XXX";
  String dbName = "XXXX";
  Object [][] a = {{1,1,"Blocked","20160622","12:29:23",1,"",1,"XXX","MANUAL","test 404"}};
  Long testSetId = 1L;
  List<?> defectList = null;
  ArrayList<List<?>> alist = new ArrayList<List<?>>(1);
  List<List<?>> list = alist;
  List<?> listNew = twoDArrayToList(a);
  list.add(listNew);
  ListIterator<?> it = list.listIterator();
  List<TestInstance> testList = getTestInstanceList();
  TestInstancesDaoImpl testInstancesDaoImpl = new TestInstancesDaoImpl();
  testInstancesDaoImpl.setALMDatabaseDao(almDatabaseDao);
  PowerMockito.mockStatic(HibernateUtil.class);
  when(almDatabaseDao.getDBName("XXX", "XX", "Staging")).thenReturn(dbName);
  when(HibernateUtil.getSession(dbName, "Staging")).thenReturn(session);
  when(session.beginTransaction()).thenReturn(transaction);
  when(session.createQuery(sqlQueryForTestInstances)).thenReturn(q);
  when(q.setParameter("cycleId", testSetId)).thenReturn(q);
  when(q.list()).thenReturn(list);
  when(session.createQuery(sqlQueryForDefects)).thenReturn(query);
  when(query.setParameter("cycleId", testSetId)).thenReturn(query);
 List<TestInstance> testInstanceList=   testInstancesDaoImpl.getAllTestInstances(domain, projectName, id, server);
 }
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear, and the broken indentation of the code makes it very hard to read.

Comment: Can you please include also the test's code?

Comment: I have modified question and added by test code